# Spring security with multiple providers

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I am setting up an app with 2 differents users:

- one from my ldap that can connect with cas authentication
- one external, hard coded with a simple formlogin

I created 2 Security configurations:

External User Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class SecurityVanuatuConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user =
        User.withUsername("user")
            .password("{noop}user")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable().antMatcher("/user/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL)
        .failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL)
        .successHandler(successHandler)
        .failureHandler(successHandler)
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL);
}
```

Cas Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(2)
public class SecurityCasConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/admin/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter())
        .addFilterBefore(casLogoutFilter(), CasAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public SingleSignOutFilter casLogoutFilter() {
    SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
    return singleSignOutFilter;
}

// if I remove this bean, external configuration works
@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
    CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    provider.setTicketValidator(new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator("https://sso.unc.nc/cas"));
    provider.setKey("cas");
    provider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(successHandler);
    return provider;
}
```

Each configuration work when it's alone, but when there is both, the external doesn't work.

It seems that the CasAuthenticationProvider bean prevent the formLogin to work and I endup in the FailureHandler.

Here is the error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

How can I make these 2 configuration work together?

Answer (score 0):

when you mark something as `@Bean` you are putting it in the pool of beans that spring can use to inject into classes if they need it.

you have registered

```
@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
    ...
}
```

as a `@Bean` which is an `AuthenticationProvider`. When you register this using `@Bean` it will get picked up by everyone that needs it, meaning that both your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will use it.

**Spring has no way of knowing that you only want this is in one of your security configurations and not the other.**

you have to explicitly define that you want it in one and not the other by removing `@Bean` and setting it manually.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
}

public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {
    ...
}
```

You have to always decied if you want to set something manually, or use `@Bean` and let spring inject it for you.

So for instance, you are registering a filter (casLogoutFilter) setting it manually but also defining it as `@Bean` telling spring to inject it into the filter chain, which sort of doesn't make sense.